# Can not include headerfile properly using php and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue. I could not include the proper header file using Codeigniter. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php 
$homPage=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $homPage;
if($homPage=='/takeme/'){
    include COMMON_PATH.'header.php';
}else if($homPage=='/takeme/Aboutus/'){
    include COMMON_PATH.'aboutus_header.php';
}else{
    include COMMON_PATH.'vehicle_header.php';
}
echo @$content;
include COMMON_PATH.'footer.php';
?>
```

Here my home path is `http://localhost/takeme/`

> footer.php:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo SUB_DIR.'Aboutus/Page/' ?>">About Us</a></li>
```

> AboutusController.php:

```
function Page(){
        ob_start();
        include 'View/Page/aboutus.php';
        $content=ob_get_clean();
        include 'View/Layout/index.php';
}
```

Here my problem is in `aboutus.php` both header `aboutus_header.php and vehicle_header.php` is coming where I need `only aboutus_header.php` to include. Please help me.

Comment: share value for $homePage when you clicking on about us link?

Comment: Use `elseif` instead of `else if`.

Comment: @Naincy : On this `http://localhost/takeme/` page i have `aboutus` link

Comment: @u_mulder : I did as per you but still issue is there.

Comment: @subhra: '/takeme/Aboutus/' you comparing this to http://localhost/takeme/ 
then it will go to else case obliviously. Considering http://localhost/takeme/ as output of echo $homePage;

Comment: @subhra: I think you should use uri segment of codeigniter in place of using core functions of PHP.
Please see this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/uri.html

Comment: Try reading through here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world and here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Comment: And also you cannot load controller with in controller if using codeigniter MVC Also your filenaming wrong https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a typo in your `elseif` statement.

Second, you are verifying the incorrect uri path. The `Request URI` should be the same value of your `href` in your `a` html tag (`Aboutus/Page/`), adding the first part of your path (`/takeme/`).

Finally, you should have:

```
} elseif($homPage=='/takeme/Aboutus/Page'){
    include COMMON_PATH.'aboutus_header.php';
}
```

Comment: I did as per you but this time same header including two times.

Comment: In that case, you are including the other header in from other file or function